# How to iterate through this std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have this pointer to `std::vector` as a class member:

```
std::vector<std::vector<vec3d<GLshort>*>*> *faces = new std::vector<std::vector<vec3d<GLshort>*>*>();
```

To iterate it I am trying this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<vec3d<GLshort>*>*>::iterator it;
for (it = this->faces->begin();
    it != this->faces->end();
    ++it) {
    it->...
}
```

It does not allow me to access to `it` members. What am I missing?

Comment: Why not just `for(auto it : faces)`

Comment: time to redesign your code. store values in vectors, not pointers. Even if the value is an object that contains a pointer.

Comment: "It does not allow me to access to it members." this code seem to be ok, if you are getting an error you should post it here.

Comment: so I should not store a single pointer in a std::vector, right?

Comment: `it->` is of type `std::vector<T>::pointer` since you store pointers, that's a pointer to a pointer... heed what Tas and Richard tell you, but generally when you store pointers in a vector, you have to double dereference the iterator: `(*it)->do_stuff()`.

Comment: @E.Williams You should rather use `std::unique_ptr` instead of storing raw pointers.

Comment: It is unusual to have pointers to vectors. It is *extremely* unusual to have pointers to vectors of pointers to vectors of pointers to 3D vectors. Either you do something that *is* extremely unusual, or this is not the best way of doing that.

Comment: Wow, the number of indirection steps necessary to reach an actual coordinate in this code is definitely remarkable... `(*(*(*this->faces)[0])[0])[0]`, looks like a sextuple pointer in disguise and I'm not even sure I got it right.

Comment: "pointer to std::vector" there seems to be your problem. Why do you need a pointer to a vector?

Comment: Thanks for your tips guys, I will redesign the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change `it->` to `(*it)->` in your code. Because `it` is working like a `std::vector<> **it` in your code.

Comment: @BoPersson thank you for your advice, i have edited my answer.